# How can I verify / trust the location of an iOS or Android device from the server?

Tags: android, ios, security, geolocation

I am writing the server to back a location-based app for iOS and Android. The app requires that we verify both the identity of the user and their location. I know how to do the former, but not the latter.

Is it possible to verify that the lat/lon the client is sending me is in fact the device's best estimate of the its current location? I'm worried about a malicious client spoofing a location and gaming the system.

**CLARIFICATION:** I would like to know how a server can *trust*, through some kind of verification process, the locations it is sent.

I can figure out how to get the user's location from the device. For example, on the Android platform my app would register to receive [android.location.Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)s, pull out the lat/lon, and send it to the server.

But how do I convince the server that I didn't just make it up? From the server's perspective, why should it believe, when given a lat/lon, that the user is actually there (or close to there given the accuracy)?

Perhaps there's some way of signing the data?

How do the servers for apps like foursquare and Facebook verify that the location data they're being given isn't being faked?

Answer (score 0):

Write your own android or iOS client. As I am working on android it is very simple code. You need to write one service which runs on given period of time. This service will fetch the location. By this you will be sure that what ever lat/long you are receiving is only by your code. Now next point is accuracy. You can use criteria class in android. You can define your own criteria for fetching location.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how the server can verify that the location data it's receiving is actually genuine? See clarification above.

Comment: Yes its genuine. And You have to store the lat/long in the perticular xml/Json file. That file will be updated periodicly by the posted lat/long from the device. and that data should be fetched by the user and then can able to see the updated lat/long. Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Write service in Android and iOS that post the current lat/long periodicaly to the server. 
And Also write code that fetch the lat/long periodicaly from the server and manipulate it to the Android or IOS map.

Enjoy. :))

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how the server can verify that the location data it's receiving is actually genuine? See clarification above.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, I don't believe it's possible to detect location spoofing on iOS when done using Xcode and GPX files to simulate location. All apps, even the iOS Map's app will believe your location is whatever it is set in the GPX file used to simulate your location via Xcode.

More info on this method: http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2013/04/spoofing-location-services-in-ios/